# Pivoting data and keeping only specific rows as per a condition

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe with multiple columns, which looks like the following:

| Index | ID | Year | Code | #Purchase | Mode |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 100 | 2018 | ABC | 1 | 1 |
| 1 | 100 | 2019 | DEF | 2 | 2 |
| 2 | 100 | 2019 | GHI | 3 | 3 |
| 3 | 102 | 2018 | JKL | 4 | 2 |
| 4 | 103 | 2019 | MNO | 5 | 1 |
| 5 | 103 | 2020 | PQR | 6 | 2 |
| 6 | 102 | 2019 | PQR | 3 | 3 |
| 7 | 104 | 2019 | LMN | 3 | 1 |
| 7 | 104 | 2021 | LMN | 1 | 3 |

I want to group rows w.r.t to ID and then pivot the results and would only like to keep IDs that have an entry against Mode_1 then Mode_2 and then Mode_3. The result should look like this:

| Index | ID | Year_1 | Code_1 | #Purchase_1 | Mode_1 | Year_2 | Code_2 | #Purchase_2 | Mode_2 | Year_3 | Code_3 | #Purchase_3 | Mode_3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 100 | 2018 | ABC | 1 | 1 | 2019 | DEF | 2 | 2 | 2019 | GHI | 3 | 3 |
| 1 | 103 | 2019 | MNO | 5 | 1 | 2020 | PQR | 6 | 2 | NaN | NaN | NaN | NaN |

In the example results, we can see that ID 102 is dropped because it doesn't have a `Mode` = 1, and ID 104 is dropped because the `Mode` value skips 2. So the possible combinations of `Mode` against an ID needed are 1, 1-->2, or 1-->2-->3.

It would be really appreciated if someone could help me with this example problem.
TIA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use:

```
#filter if difference is 1 per groups
m1 = df.groupby('ID')['Mode'].transform(lambda x: x.diff().iloc[1:].eq(1).all())
#filter if first value per group is 1
m2 = df.groupby('ID')['Mode'].transform('first').eq(1)
  
#pivoting all columns by ID per groups g created by copy Mode column
df = df[m1 & m2].assign(g = lambda x: x['Mode']).pivot(index='ID', columns='g').sort_index(axis=1, level=1)
#flatten MultiIndex
df.columns = df.columns.map(lambda x: f'{x[0]}_{x[1]}')
df = df.reset_index()
print (df)
    ID  #Purchase_1 Code_1  Mode_1  Year_1  #Purchase_2 Code_2  Mode_2  \
0  100          1.0    ABC     1.0  2018.0          2.0    DEF     2.0   
1  103          5.0    MNO     1.0  2019.0          6.0    PQR     2.0   

   Year_2  #Purchase_3 Code_3  Mode_3  Year_3  
0  2019.0          3.0    GHI     3.0  2019.0  
1  2020.0          NaN    NaN     NaN     NaN
```